# Website forces scrapy redirect

Tags: python, scrapy

I keep on getting redirected from www.caribbeanjobs.com. I've programmed my spider to not obey the robot.txt, disabled cookies, tried meta=dont_redirect. What else can I do?

This is my spider below:

```
import scrapy

from tutorial.items import CaribbeanJobsItem

class CaribbeanJobsSpider(scrapy.Spider):
        name = "caribbeanjobs"
        allowed_domains = ["caribbeanjobs.com/"]
        start_urls = [
        "http://www.caribbeanjobs.com/"
        ]
        def start_requests(self):
            for url in self.start_urls:
                yield scrapy.Request(url, meta={'dont_redirect':True})

        def parse(self, response):
                if ".com" in response.url:
                        from scrapy.shell import inspect_response
                        inspect_response(response, self)
```

These are my settings:

```
BOT_NAME = 'tutorial'

SPIDER_MODULES = ['tutorial.spiders']
NEWSPIDER_MODULE = 'tutorial.spiders'


# Crawl responsibly by identifying yourself (and your website) on the user-agent
#USER_AGENT = 'tutorial (+http://www.yourdomain.com)'

# Obey robots.txt rules
ROBOTSTXT_OBEY = False

# Configure maximum concurrent requests performed by Scrapy (default: 16)
#CONCURRENT_REQUESTS = 32

# Configure a delay for requests for the same website (default: 0)
# See http://scrapy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html#download-delay
# See also autothrottle settings and docs
DOWNLOAD_DELAY = 3
# The download delay setting will honor only one of:
#CONCURRENT_REQUESTS_PER_DOMAIN = 16
#CONCURRENT_REQUESTS_PER_IP = 16

# Disable cookies (enabled by default)
COOKIES_ENABLED = False

# Disable Telnet Console (enabled by default)
#TELNETCONSOLE_ENABLED = False

# Override the default request headers:
#DEFAULT_REQUEST_HEADERS = {
#   'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
#   'Accept-Language': 'en',
#}

# Enable or disable spider middlewares
# See http://scrapy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/topics/spider-middleware.html
#SPIDER_MIDDLEWARES = {
#    'tutorial.middlewares.MyCustomSpiderMiddleware': 543,
#}

# Enable or disable downloader middlewares
# See http://scrapy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/topics/downloader-middleware.html
#DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES = {
#    'tutorial.middlewares.MyCustomDownloaderMiddleware': 543,
#}

# Enable or disable extensions
# See http://scrapy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/topics/extensions.html
#EXTENSIONS = {
#    'scrapy.extensions.telnet.TelnetConsole': None,
#}

# Configure item pipelines
# See http://scrapy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/topics/item-pipeline.html
#ITEM_PIPELINES = {
#    'tutorial.pipelines.SomePipeline': 300,
#}

# Enable and configure the AutoThrottle extension (disabled by default)
# See http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/autothrottle.html
#AUTOTHROTTLE_ENABLED = True
# The initial download delay
#AUTOTHROTTLE_START_DELAY = 5
# The maximum download delay to be set in case of high latencies
#AUTOTHROTTLE_MAX_DELAY = 60
# The average number of requests Scrapy should be sending in parallel to
# each remote server
#AUTOTHROTTLE_TARGET_CONCURRENCY = 1.0
# Enable showing throttling stats for every response received:
#AUTOTHROTTLE_DEBUG = False

# Enable and configure HTTP caching (disabled by default)
# See http://scrapy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/topics/downloader-middleware.html#httpcache-middleware-settings
#HTTPCACHE_ENABLED = True
#HTTPCACHE_EXPIRATION_SECS = 0
#HTTPCACHE_DIR = 'httpcache'
#HTTPCACHE_IGNORE_HTTP_CODES = []
#HTTPCACHE_STORAGE = 'scrapy.extensions.httpcache.FilesystemCacheStorage'
```

Comment: It might check your useragent and always redirect you, if you haven't been respecting their site with your bot

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you try setting an explicit `USER_AGENT` in your settings?

http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html#user-agent

Something like this might work as a starting point:

```
USER_AGENT = "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_6_8) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/32.0.1700.102 Safari/537.36"`
```

Comment: This worked, thank you so much! I'm guessing that because my user agent wasn't a browser, they would instantly redirect me. Is this correct?

Comment: They could be looking for nonstandard user agents or spacy's default might be something they're explicitly watching out for.  There's essentially an arms race against content scrapers and content publishers.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify handle_http_status. You can initialize this list post start_urls.

```
handle_http_status = ['303', '301']
```

Comment: you can also do this as Request meta key i.e. `Request(url, meta={'handdle_httpstatus_list': [303, 301]}`

Comment: Yes, you are correct we can do like that as well. But the one I mentioned will have effect global.

Answer (score 0):

Use a custom download middleware to handle such redirections:

```
'DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES' : {
    'projectname.middlewares.RandomProxyForReDirectedUrls': 650
}
```

Add a new class in projectname\middlewares.py:

```
class RandomProxyForReDirectedUrls(object):
    def process_response(self, request, response, spider):
        if response.status in [303, 301]:
            if "_some_wrongly_redirected_url_identifier_" in response.url:
                request = request.replace(url=request.meta['redirect_urls'][0])
                request.dont_filter = True
                logging.error("Redirecting back to original url: %s" % request.meta['redirect_urls'][0])
                return request
            else:
                return response
```

This will redirect to original link if condition is meet, otherwise continue as normal.

Comment: or disable the retry middle:
'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.RedirectMiddleware': None,